# Custom module with its own menu?

Tags: 7, routes, hooks

I am in the process of writing my 3rd custom module and this one is my biggest challenge yet.
I know how to use hook_menu to generate menu items, and depending on the path you choose determines where they show up on the site (administration menu or main menu, etc).

My question is - how do I specify a NEW menu, so that the paths I create do not appear in "primary links" or "navigation" but in their own "custom module" menu?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You specify the menu_name parameter.

*From the devel module:*

```
$items['devel/cache/clear'] = array(
  'title' => 'Empty cache',
  'page callback' => 'devel_cache_clear',
  'description' => 'Clear the CSS cache and all database cache tables which store page, node, theme and variable caches.',
  'access arguments' => array('access devel information'),
  'menu_name' => 'devel',
);
```

Comment: Note that you will need to create your menu first in hook_install() or so. The menu system doesn't automatically create a menu for you. See http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--devel--devel.install/function/devel_install/6