# Custom module with its own menu block

Tags: routes

I am trying to create a module that supplies a custom menu block, that changes based on what organic group you are looking at. I'm confused by the documentation, so I thought I'd ask here. I saw [an answer for Drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1276/custom-module-with-its-own-menu), but I'm using Drupal 6.

og_menu doesn't work for me because I don't want group admins to change it. I just want the default to be dynamic based on some logic of my own.

Specifically, should I supply a custom block from my module? If so, how do I render the list of links I create, or should be supplying a custom menu? What hook do I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you'd really want to supply a hook_block, whose $content will call a custom PHP function that will construct your array of links to other organic groups, based on your criteria.

Comment: I'm trying that (supplying a custom block), but what is the proper D6 way to construct & render a menu from a block?  Is it just to call `l()` a whole bunch?

Comment: You could construct the link array yourself with PHP, or if you have specific menus, something like menu_get_menu I think... but I don't know what your criteria is.